# How to cast method of a class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

My goal is to be able to declare a method without repeating the param types and the return type. I used typescript `Type` for that.

But now, how to tell Typescript that `heyy Typescript, this method sum is of type IBar`

```
type IBar = (x:number, y: number)=>number;
class Foo {
    sum(x,y){
        return x+y;
    } as IBar
}
```

I tried

```
type IBar = (x:number, y: number)=>number;
class Foo {
    sum:IBar=(x,y)=>{
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

BUT unfortunately, this changes the javascript code transpiled into:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.sum = (x, y) => {
            return x + y;
        };
    }
}
```

I am looking for something that transpiles into:

```
class Foo {
    sum(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgQgQwE5QLxQBQA8BcA7AVwFsAjCJAGihBykNPIEpUA+espAbgFgAoPgMYAbBAGdRUAGIB7aVADefKMqijiteMjSYsVEIzQsoWKAGpqPXgF8gA) any helpful? I am not sure if I understand your question just right.

Comment: I already figured out this answer and it works but the problem is that javascrit compiled code needs to be `class Foo {
    sum(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}` instead of  `class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.sum = (x, y) => {
            return x + y;
        };
    }
}`

Comment: I fear you're out of luck if you want that exact compiled javascript code. The closest I can think of is making use of a interface => [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE5WQb2QZwFcBbACgA8AuZEEgI2gBpkBPa24hqASnfugDcyAL4BYAFASEAGzj58yAGIB7ZcmDEADtIjEI4BRiy4JyM8k2E604AgIkKfTk1ZOuvGv2w5T5v1AgwQigQZHJkAGpWAV8zMXFhIA)

Comment: I also though of this but the problem is it would bind the method name to only `sum` . What if I want to use the same method type with a different name like `divide` or `multiply`

Comment: That is right, however I dont think you can implicitly type a function (to get the desired compiled javascript) without a property that you can put your typing on.